# How to change menu labels

Tags: php, functions, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-style

What is the best approach to changing admin menu labels? As part of my first step in modifying the admin area, I would like to know how I can change **WooCommerce** label to **Shop**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change the menu labels you will have to go to add this code into your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_woocommerce_text' );

function change_woocommerce_text( $translated ) 
{  
    $translated = str_replace( 'WooCommerce', 'Store', $translated );
    return $translated;
}
```

Tested.

Comment: Thank you for the code, I've copied your code into my functions.php and it seem that the label have not change. Is the code you given was not tested?

Comment: It's tested, I just updated my answer with and screen shoot. Try to add that code at the bottom of the fuctions.php file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. (Exp: I have changed label 'Post' to 'Articles')

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_change_admin_label', 99);
function custom_change_admin_label() {
    global $menu;
    //global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'Articles';
}
```

Screenshot: http://nimb.ws/jiIC91